# Sort two different column indexes in two seperate JS DataTables

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I have a site using `DataTables` to format two tables on the same page. Currently I am able to display and use both tables (see below), but I cannot order both tables individually at separate indices. One table has 8 columns, another has 11, and I would like to sort each of them by the last column. Is there a way to sort these during initialization or afterwards?

Example sorting both tables by the 8th column:

```
$('table.display').DataTable({
    dom: 'f<br/>Btipr',
    order: [[ 7, "asc" ]],
    buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Save Table Excel',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'Save Table Csv',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'Save Table PDF',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Columns',
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using class selector, use the Id selector to write code for two tables individually like so:

HTML:

```
<table class="display" id="table1Id"></table>
<table class="display" id="table2Id"></table>
```

JS:

```
$('table#table1Id').DataTable({
    dom: 'f<br/>Btipr',
    order: [[ 7, "asc" ]],
    buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Save Table Excel',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'Save Table Csv',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'Save Table PDF',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Columns',
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
    }]
});

$('table#table2Id').DataTable({
    dom: 'f<br/>Btipr',
    order: [[ 10, "asc" ]],
    buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Save Table Excel',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'Save Table Csv',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'Save Table PDF',
            filename: input + "_Table",
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
        },{
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Columns',
            className: "btn btn-outline-dark"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Worked and lets me individualize the formatting, thanks for the solution!